# Force loading kernel module at startup

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, modprobe

Some of my hardware needs the module cx23885. 
For some reason `modprode cx23885` doesn't work, instead only `modprobe cx23885 --force-modversion` works.

This hardware is currently somewhat buggy and only recognized (with lspci) after a full poweroff and clean start.

Is there any possibility to load the module at boot with the force or force-version option? I know it works without any options just putting it into `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the module with your currently-installed kernel? That should fix the `modversion` problems.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate? https://askubuntu.com/questions/51226/how-to-add-kernel-module-parameters

To expand on what is mentioned there, modprobe options no longer work in /etc/modules-load.d/. They can go into /etc/modprobe.d/ in a text file named something like 99-cx23385.conf

```
# fix loading of cx23885 module
options cx23385 --force-modversion
```

Since I don't have this hardware to test, if systemd stubbornly tries to modprobe cx23885 instead of the working module, try making it an alias (insert after options line above).

```
alias cx23885 cx23385
```

And, at last, if it tries loading both modules or there is a conflict, try blacklisting the offending module.

References: `man modprobe.d` and `man systemd`

Comment: Addendum: The manpage for modprobe.d says you can put options right into the alias, so they don't need to be separate lines.

Comment: My file looks like this now: alias cx cx23885 --force-modversion. But modprobe cx still gives me the same problem as before. Before i tried options cx23885 --force or options cx23885 --force-modversion.  Somehow these options get ignored. Seems like i'm doing something wrong, because with modprobe directly everything works fine

Comment: It says you can also use the install command to force the module to take arguments. Another hack I heard about is to insert the module with options right into the grub kernel boot parameters and update grub.